# visual basic for application Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code in module 1. I get the correct value for the output. But, When I call it in module 2, the output value is zero. I would be thankful, if anyone can help me.

Module 1:

```
Sub MuAndVuCalculations() 
BeamFlangeWidth = Sheets("MuVu").Range("D7") 
BeamFlangeThickness = Sheets("MuVu").Range("D8") 
BeamWebHeight = Sheets("MuVu").Range("D9") 
M3 = (0.5 * BeamFlangeWidth * BeamWebHeight * BeamWebHeight ^ 2) 
End Sub
```

module 2:

```
Sub Main() 
Call MuAndVuCalculations 
M = 5 Debug.Print M3 + M 
End Sub
```

In module 2 I can not see M3 in Immediate window and the output of the M3+5 is 5

Comment: Please show your code? It's hard to figure out the issue from the information you have given so far

Comment: The code is a little too long. May I have your email address? I attache the file and send it to you.

Comment: post only the relavant code

Comment: Module 1:Sub MuAndVuCalculations()
BeamFlangeWidth = Sheets("MuVu").Range("D7")
BeamFlangeThickness = Sheets("MuVu").Range("D8")
BeamWebHeight = Sheets("MuVu").Range("D9")
M3 = (0.5 * BeamFlangeWidth * BeamWebHeight * BeamWebHeight ^ 2)
       End Sub
module 2:Sub Main()
Call MuAndVuCalculations
M = 5
Debug.Print M3 + M
End Sub
        In module 2 I can not see M3 in Immediate window and the output of the M3+5 is 5.

Comment: @AlexP could you find the problem?

Comment: See `Katz` solution below. You don't provide a way to make `M3` accessible outside of `MuAndVuCalculations`. Either make `M3` a public variable (see Katz below) or make `MuAndVuCalculations` a function that returns a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `M3` as `public` to access from the other function.
Add the first line above your code in module1:

```
Public M3 As Long 'add this line

Sub MuAndVuCalculations()
BeamFlangeWidth = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("D7")
BeamFlangeThickness = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("D8")
BeamWebHeight = Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("D9")
M3 = (0.5 * BeamFlangeWidth * BeamWebHeight * BeamWebHeight ^ 2)
End Sub
```